# Is there a better way of updating a data grid then just adding and removing the datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a **List** collection where **UserPropDef** is a custom class with a few public properties. I want to display the contents of this list in a **DataGrid**. So I set the **DataGrid.DataSource** property of my grid to the list and it displays the contents just as I want.

Now if I add or remove items from the list I want the **DataGrid** to update. I can't use a **BindingList** because this list needs to be serialized. I've tried calling the **Update()** and **Refresh()** methods of both the **DataGrid**, and the form and nothing seems to cause the **DataGrid** to refresh based on the current contents of the collection.

The only thing that works seems to be setting the **DataSource** property again. Yet when debugging my code I can see that after the collection has changed the **DataSource** property of the DataGrid is in fact still referencing the correct and updated collection.

Is there a better way to cause the **DataGrid** to refresh based on it's current **DataSource**?

Comment: Holy bold identifiers, Batman!

Comment: I removed my answer since I incorrectly assumed your question was about asp.net. I added the winforms tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be take what is behind door number 3:

Create a custom Serializable List that implements IBindingList (Or something that inherits from BindingList and fixes the Serializable issues. Check out [Fixing BindingList...](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/07/17/fixing-bindinglist-deserialization/) for ideas).